# What's the purpose of FOREIGN KEY (Key_Name) REFERENCES null (null);

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

I encountered a situation where the table was defined with this foreign key syntax.

```
FOREIGN KEY (DATE_KEY) 
    REFERENCES null (null);
```

I am confused with this syntax. As foreign key in one table acts as a primary key in another table.

Could you please take time to explain this.

Thanks

Comment: is this for Oracle11g or sql-Server?

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid syntax.

Comment: That's definitely invalid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

FROM - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx

A foreign key (FK) is a column or combination of columns that is used to establish and enforce a link between the data in two tables.

In a foreign key reference, a link is created between two tables when the column or columns that hold the primary key value for one table are referenced by the column or columns in another table. This column becomes a foreign key in the second table.

I know there are people that doe odd things in databases all the time, but a cannot for the life of me figure out why anyone would ever want a FOREIGN KEY that references null.

Comment: So As per your comments, There is no really use of doing this? the tables that i am looking on, there are 10 foreign key columns that are referenced to Null. Just I want to know the intention of guy who coded that and he is no more working here. Anyway Thanks Vincent..